# Java : spring boot cannot parse date from angular moment

Tags: angular, spring-boot, momentjs, jhipster, localdate

I have generated a Jhipster project with angular as the front-end. I have a reactive form in angular to enter data. The problem is that when I'm trying to save an entity with a LocalDate attribute, I'm facing this error:

```
JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "2021-01-Tu": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2021-01-Tu' could not be parsed at index 8; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "2021-01-Tu": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2021-01-Tu' could not be parsed at index 8↵ at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 27] (through reference chain: com.icomg.stariol.service.dto.ExerciceDTO["debut"])
```

This is what I'm doing:

ExerciceDTO.java:

```
public class ExerciceDTO implements Serializable {

    private Long id;

    private String libelle;

    private LocalDate debut;

    private LocalDate fin;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLibelle() {
        return libelle;
    }

    public void setLibelle(String libelle) {
        this.libelle = libelle;
    }

    public LocalDate getDebut() {
        return debut;
    }

    public void setDebut(LocalDate debut) {
        this.debut = debut;
    }

    public LocalDate getFin() {
        return fin;
    }

    public void setFin(LocalDate fin) {
        this.fin = fin;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof ExerciceDTO)) {
            return false;
        }

        return id != null && id.equals(((ExerciceDTO) o).id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }

    // prettier-ignore
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ExerciceDTO{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", libelle='" + getLibelle() + "'" +
            ", debut='" + getDebut() + "'" +
            ", fin='" + getFin() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}
```

exercice.model.ts

```
export interface IExercice {
  id?: number;
  libelle?: string;
  debut?: Moment;
  fin?: Moment;
  calendrierFiscals?: ICalendrierFiscal[];
}

export class Exercice implements IExercice {
  constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public libelle?: string,
    public debut?: Moment,
    public fin?: Moment,
    public calendrierFiscals?: ICalendrierFiscal[]
  ) {}
}
```

excercice-update.component.html:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                    <mat-label  jhiTranslate="gatewayApp.exercice.debut" for="field_debut">Debut</mat-label>
                        <input id="field_debut" type="text" name="debut" matInput formControlName="debut" [matDatepicker]="picker1"/>
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                    <mat-label jhiTranslate="gatewayApp.exercice.fin" for="field_fin">Fin</mat-label>
                        <input id="field_fin" type="text" matInput name="fin" [matDatepicker]="picker2" formControlName="fin"/>
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
```

exercice-update.component.ts:

```
private createFromForm(): IExercice {
    return {
      ...new Exercice(),
      id: this.editForm.get(['id'])!.value,
      libelle: this.editForm.get(['libelle'])!.value,
      debut: moment(this.editForm.get(['debut'])!.value),
      fin: moment(this.editForm.get(['fin'])!.value),
    };
  }
```

Comment: If this is your input date `2021-01-Tu` looks like this in wrong format

Comment: The problem is that I'm entering the date from the angular side. And the format is correct there when I display it with console.log()

Comment: I found the solution. The problem was linked to the method I used to convert the date